# ACE_DLL::open failed for some dll file

Tags: c++, ace

I am quite puzzled by this error. The complete error information is as below.

ACE_DLL::open failed for TestFE.dll: Error: check log for details.
Unable to find service: MySvc

But if I take another TestBE.dll, it can be started successfully.

BTW: there is no missing dependent dll file for TestFE.dll. The PATH in Windows is correct to locate the TestFE.dll. I try to compare the project build options between TestBE.dll and TestFE.dll but with no findings.

Can anybody here help me figure out the reason? Thank you.

Comment: Build versions may be different ?

Comment: I am quite puzzled by this question.  It is *very* poorly documented, you need to do a better job Mr. Fan.

Comment: Perhaps check that log for details or put more details or a code snippet here so we have some more context?

Answer (score 0):

I spend 7 working days to find out the reason. It is because two different versions of dependent dll files exist. During compilation time I can compile it with one version, but during runtime it loads another version. The DEPENDS.exe searches for the dependent dll file version that the compilation time takes, while ACE searches the version are the runtime version. So you will see no dependent dll file is lost. But in runtime, ACE always gets the wrong dll files so that it fails to load dlls.

Comment: I fail to open the ACE log. I do not know why so far. Actually I am working on a platform which is developed based on ACE.